# Populate JTable with a JButton only works the first time

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I populated the `jTable` `jtBusqueda` with the `jButton` `jbBuscarActionPerformed`. The first time it worked as expected, but when value was altered (2nd time) it didn't work.

My code for the button is:

```
   private void jbBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                         
        //get data from database
        clsDBBusca dbengine2 = new clsDBBusca();
        try {
            data2 = dbengine2.getBusqueda();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(clsCodif2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //create header for the table
        header2 = new Vector<String>();
        header2.add("Cve"); //Cve
        header2.add("Descripcion"); // Caracteristica Principal

        jtBusqueda.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
            (
                data2, header2
            )
        initComponents();

    } 

    public Vector getBusqueda()throws Exception
        {
            Vector<Vector<String>> resultadoVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

            Connection conn = dbConnection();
            PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Clave_Nueva, Descripcion_Especificaciones FROM famMat_Especificaciones WHERE Descripcion_Especificaciones like '%" + jtBuscaTexto.getText() + "%'");

            ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                Vector<String> resultado = new Vector<String>();
                resultado.add(rs.getString(1)); //Cve
                resultado.add(rs.getString(2)); //Descripcion de la busqueda
                resultadoVector.add(resultado);
            }

            /*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
            if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();

            return resultadoVector;

     }
```

Comment: Note: You're not using prepared statements the way they're supposed to be used. Read about that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). What you're doing is potentially dangerous on a security standpoint, which is why I'm mentioning it :)

Comment: Is your `initComponents();` call an auto-generated method that Netbeans generates for you? If so, it's not doing what you think it's doing. If not, what is that doing?

Comment: Awful code style. You should also write english code if you request help on an english site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
jtBusqueda.repaint();
```